# Compare two array of values and create one array PHP

Tags: php, loops

i am developing an application to devide a set of values to customers.Each customer have a limit value (Total value split based on percentage assigned to customer)

For example:
Total value is 339269
Customer 1 assigned a percentage of 39% - then value limit become : 132314
Customer 2 assigned a percentage of 34% - then value limit become : 115351
Customer 3 assigned a percentage of 27% - then value limit become : 91602

```
$valueArray = array('67212','37256','32909','29847','28529','27643','25356','25274','23604','23058','18581');
$customer = array('132314','115351','91602');
```

I want to arrange the value array in customer column by adding each value to column without crossing its limit.

Out put will be an array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 67212
            [1] => 27643
            [2] => 25356
            [3] => 18581
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 37256
            [1] => 28529
            [2] => 25274
            [3] => 23058

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 32909
            [1] => 29847
            [2] => 23604
        )

)
```

Real Output will be like, the arrow showing the flow of adding data. loop will work same way.

[image]

And i tried like, but not getting currect

```
function parse(array $valueArr, array $customerArr)
{
    $customerCount = count($customerArr);
    $chunkedValueArr = array_chunk($valueArr, $customerCount);
    $temp = array_fill(0, $customerCount, array());




    $i = 0;
    foreach ($chunkedValueArr as $item) {

        foreach ($item as $key => $value) {


            //echo $customerArr[$key]."<br/>";

            $pre_existing = isset($temp[$key]) ? array_sum($temp[$key]) : 0;



            if($pre_existing+$value <= $customerArr[$key]){

                $temp[$key][] = $value;

            }


        }
        $temp = rotateArray($temp);
        $customerArr = rotateArray($customerArr);
        $i++;
    }
    // if $i is odd
    if ($i & 1) {
        $temp = rotateArray($temp);
        //$customerArr = rotateArray($customerArr);
    }

    return $temp;
}

function rotateArray(array $arr)
{
    $rotatedArr = array();

    //set the pointer to the last element and add it to the second array
    array_push($rotatedArr, end($arr));

    //while we have items, get the previous item and add it to the second array
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($arr)-1; $i++){
        array_push($rotatedArr, prev($arr));
    }

    return $rotatedArr;

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(parse($valueArray, $customer));
```

Comment: where is the problem ? you should write some code and showing the part exactly where you have problems.

Comment: please check i added

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand what you're trying to do here. Where are the percentages, and what are the numbers in $customer in your example? And why is there an empty  [1][4] in your output example. Please make your question clearer.

Comment: I've really tried to understand what is going on here, but I can't. I understand that you want to re-arange your array from customers and value's. The point I am not getting is what the value should be arranged on, I can't find a similarity in it. To me the resultant array just looks absolutly random, if you could clearify that, I am sure I can help you!

Comment: Customer array is just the upper limit. means percentage of total. just i want to compare each item in value array with customer limit.that is each time when adding take total of that array and check if it exceed when we add current value..But when the first time we parsing the loop from 0 to 2, then next time it will become 2 to 0 and then 0 to 2, 2 to 0. etc

Comment: customer array is same as customer list in the image...as customer 1 , customer 2 and customer 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my sollution:

```
        function parse(array $valueArr, array $customerArr)
{
    $customerCount =count($customerArr);
    $temp          =array_fill(0, $customerCount, array());
    $customersTotal=array_fill(0, $customerCount, 0);
    $maxID= array_keys($customerArr, max($customerArr))[0];



    $i   =0;
    $step=1;
    foreach($valueArr as $item)
    {

        $done    =false;
        $attempts=0;

        while(!$done)
        {
            //switching directions of traversing
            if($i < 0)
            {
                $i   =0;
                $step=1;
            }
            elseif($i >= $customerCount)
            {
                $i   =$customerCount - 1;
                $step=-1;
            }


            if($customersTotal[$i] + $item <= $customerArr[$i])
            {
                $temp[$i][]=$item;
                $customersTotal[$i]+=$item;
                $done     =true;
            }
            else{
                $attempts++;
                if($attempts>$customerCount*2)
                {
                   $i=$maxID;
                   $temp[$i][]=$item;
                   $customersTotal[$i]+=$item;
                   $done     =true;

                }
            }
            $i+=$step;
        }
    }


    return $temp;
}
```

You also have error in your expected output - first customer is  over its limt

Comment: Yes...i want to place such values in column where we assigned largest percentage i mean column limit having larget limit.

Comment: @alialwafaa edited... next time try to describe more precisely what your expected output is

Comment: in your code how can we add such values into column which having largest limit.

Comment: @alialwafaa it is already done in newset version - $maxID= array_keys($customerArr, max($customerArr))[0]; is for detecting id of highest limit. if($attempts>$customerCount*2){  $i=$maxID; $temp[$i][]=$item;   forcefully add it if standart procedure fails